# MYSQLI Display/Select Data Not Working

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, mysqli

So, I made a while statement to display all of my sql data, here's my code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$row[ID]</td>
        <td>$row[USERNAME]</td>
        <td>$row[PASSWORD]</td>
        <td>$row[EMAIL]</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Don't worry about the table and /table as i have put it somewhere else.
This code was working with MySQL, but now that i changed the code to work with MySQLI, it is no longer working. My databases are set up correctly, but i get this error code on my webpage now:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in http://xxxxxxxxx on line 66 (which is the while line)

Please explain to me why this is not working in the simplest way possible. I am still a beginner at PHP and MySQLI. Also, I saw another article on this, but I have no understanding on what is going on there.

EDIT: FULL PHP CODE -

```
<?php
    //MYSQLI LOGIN DETAILS
    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    //MYSQLI CREATE CONNECTION
    $constatus = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    //MYSQLI CHECK CONNECTION
    if ($constatus->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $constatus->connect_error);
    }
    //SELECT TABLE
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata";
    $result = $constatus->query($sql);
    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>USERNAME</td>
        <td>PASSWORD</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
        </tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$row[ID]</td>
        <td>$row[USERNAME]</td>
        <td>$row[PASSWORD]</td>
        <td>$row[EMAIL]</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: too many possible reasons and too many unknowns; show full code and connection API

Comment: *"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean"* - There are quite a few duplicates on Stack for this, and your question may end up getting closed based on that.

Comment: added the full code. Yes i know, but I dont understand anything anyone says there

Comment: simple: you didn't choose a database.

Comment: How do i select one? i followed this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: look at what you posted for code and look at the tutorial again. You have 3 variables for connection, where they have 4.